# JavaFX PathTransition using pause() method

Tags: javafx

I am trying to animate a circle in a circular path using PathTransition and with the slider, trying to change its speed. Even if it is not very efficient it is working as I want.

When slider hits the 0 and after increasing the value, the circle does not continue from where it was (as expected I guess), that's why I am calling pathTransition.pause() when the slider gives the value 0.

So far so good, but the moment I increase the slider value, the animation starts to move in the reverse direction.

What could cause this and why? and how can I solve this?

Here's a GIF of the problem:

[image: gif of problem]

And my code:

```
PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setPath(outerPath);
        pathTransition.setNode(circle1);
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
        pathTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
            long fps = 50L;
            long interval = 1000000000L / fps;
            long last = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(now - last > interval){
                    if(slider.getValue() == 0){
                        pathTransition.pause();
                    }
                    else{
                        pathTransition.setRate(slider.getValue());
                        pathTransition.play();
                    }
                    last = now;
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the animation is reversing, but note that `rate` is one of the few properties which can be changed while the animation is running and actually have an effect. Using an `AnimationTimer` to synchronize the state between the animation and slider, however, is overkill. Consider binding (bidirectional or unidirectional) the `rate` property of the animation and the `value` property of the slider instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Slaw, I removed AnimationTimer and used bidirectional binding instead, now it is working properly.
`pathTransition.rateProperty().bindBidirectional(slider.valueProperty());`